# Error installing Ubuntu Server 18.04: Invalid Poolname

Tags: server, 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 but I get stuck every time at the partitioning stage, in the "removing previous storage devices" process.

FYI, the installation has been tried using three different HDDs. In each HDD, Windows 7 was correctly installed after the Ubuntu Server failure (just for testing purposes), and the installation was tried with unpartitioned HDD and ext fs partition.

Just in case the attached screenshots are unavailable, here is a brief transcription of them:

**Main Screenshot**: Installation is aborted while `removing previous storage devices` is processed.

**Log Screenshot**: Several errors are shown, such as:

`finish: cmd_install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: removing previous storage devices`

`finish: cmd_install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: curtin command block-meta`

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/curtin/block/zfs.py", line 207, in zpool.
_export raise ValueError("Invalid poolname: %s", poolname)

ValueError: ('Invalid poolname: %s', None)

('Invalid poolname: %s', None)
```

Main Screenshot:

[image]

Log Screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Get the real [server installer](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso) from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/, or try the [network-based installer](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/). The new-fangled "subiquity" installer is suitable only for the simplest use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AlexP  , but unfortunately both methods returned exactly the same errors. Must the HDD be set to a certain partitioning state (though I tried several states, as I pointed out in my first post)?

Comment: In further tests I've found out that the very same .iso (server installer, not Live) is installed without problems as a Virtual Machine in my main PC.
For the install on the server machine, I use a USB stick where the .iso file was burnt using UnetBootin. Might this be the problem, should I use any other method or is it related to hardware issues?
Best regards,

Comment: They *cannot* return "exactly" the same errors, for the the simple reason that `curtin` exists only in subiquity; the traditional d-i installer does not have this component. Moreover, in the traditional installer you can open a second virtual terminal and examine your disks, partitions etc. and set them manually.

Comment: You were completely right. I am not sure if I did not re-burn the iso files correctly in the USB, if I use the wrong USB stick or if it was something related to Unetbootin, but when I did it again, this time with UUI, the installation was successful.
Thanks very much for your help.
The problem I have now is that the same USB (set as MBR) is installing without problems in a UEFI-motherboard based PC, but when I use the same USB stick in a non-UEFI one I get a blank screen with flashing underscore (I guess that no OS is detected). Is Ubuntu Server  supposed to be compatible with no UEFI MoBos?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 32-bit can boot only in BIOS mode. Ubuntu Server 64-bit can boot both in BIOS mode and UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I tried live and "real" releases suggested by AlexP, but still have the same problem.

Then I changed the software for burning the ISO to USB, from *Startup Disk Creator* to *UNetBootin*, and then the problem no longer occurred and the system successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the conversation (just a tiiiny bit)

I had the same problem, but I solved it by making a new partition in windows with no drive name and no format, then selecting it and reformatting it as ext4 and it worked.