# Ubuntu server 20.04.2 installation constantly fails

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, usb-installation

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu server 20.04.2 on an old Optiplex 3010, and the installation fails as soon as I get past the disk formatting page (Only installing on a partition).[image][image]

Comment: Did you check if your computer meets the recommended System Requirements for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yup. 2.9 GHz 2GB memory and 512 GB HDD. I'm about to try installing onto the whole disk.

Comment: Okay, I assume you're installing this for a Dual Boot option? Also, please check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050243/error-installing-ubuntu-server-18-04-invalid-poolname It's for 18.04 but has mentioned the same error.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried to install with a different image burner

Comment: I did something with reformatting the drive in windows and used 18.04 and it is working now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download the first 20.04 .iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320886/how-to-download-the-first-20-04-iso) Use *netboot/mini.iso* and buy more RAM if your system supports it.

Comment: I got it working just now by reformatting the drive in windows, and I'm working on getting more RAM but I think its sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

Idk I just need to mark as done.

I reformatted the drive in windows to be usable, but not have a drive name and no format (previously formatted as NFTS and was drive E:). Most liekly does not have to do with the version of Ubuntu used.

Comment: If you have your answer, you can accept this.